# Using video texture in Unity 5 and Android with video delay possibility

Tags: c#

By default unity doesn't compile video texture asset for android build, I'm using "Easy VideoTexture" asset and i could build android app, now i need to add a few second delay but it will cause error. I attached C# script of Easy VideoTexture, I hope to find a right way.

```
Used script:
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pyu2laqg57y6pc7/VideoManager.cs?dl=0